# Compilation issue with '.cu file'

Tags: cl.exe

I am trying compile a ".cu" file on Windows 8 but getting the following error:

```
nvcc fatal: Can not find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
```

I tried adding "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin" in PATH variable but it did not help. Any solution/suggestions?

Comment: Do you actually have a copy of Visual Studio installed?  If so, there's a batch file called vsvars32.bat in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools" which will set all the paths correctly.  Run this before running the compiler.

Comment: Do yo know that Visual Studio 14 is not supported by `nvcc` currently? Unless you explicitly specify older platform tools in Project Properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response...Yes. I changed to Visual Studio 10. Now a new issue has appeared. I am encountering  'error:identifier <variable name> is undefined ' for every variable used in the program. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually modifying the PATH environment variable, you can execute a batch script `"vsvars32.bat"` located in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools"` directory. This script sets all the environment variables correctly.